# How can I populate mongoose model conditionally?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I have following models

```
var Item = new Schema({
  type: 'String',
  vehicle: Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

var Car = new Schema({
  model: 'String',
  make: 'String'
});

var Truck = new Schema({
  model: 'String',
  make: 'String'
});
```

So when I do Item.find(), I want to populate 'vehicle' with either Car or Truck depending on 'type'

Is there a way to conditionally populate in Mongoose?

The following code shows some potential, but not very close to what I want.

```
Item.find().populate('vehicle', null, 'Car');
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can determine what the `ObjectId` is unless you populate it. So I assume that you want to populate `vehicle` and put dynamic model depending on what the `ObjectId` is? Correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `.populate('vehicle')` ? remove the model reference.

Comment: @the-green-fox, thank you for the comment, but  `.populate('vehicle')` didn't work. it just returned null for 'vehicle'.

Comment: Really? That's weird. Let me just test something, Ill get back to you.

Comment: @the-green-fox, No worries, I was able to solve the problem with 'mongoose-schema-extend' by `var Car = Item.schema.extend()` instead of `var Car = new Schema()`. This way, depending on the type of the document, either Car or Truck is populated when I execute Item.find().populate(). Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution. I glad you solved it. This might come handy for future references. Post your answer so others will see.